# $_SESSION is not insert into value

Tags: php, html, session

I want to make web using php.
In my login form, I've make a process to go to ‘menu.html’.
In this process to go menu, I did a process with name ‘auth.php’.
In ‘auth.php’ I want to make `$_SESSION` with index `$_SESSION['id_user']` to get `id_user` from my table ‘user’, but in ‘menu.html’ when I want to access it doesn't work from that session. Do you have any idea to solve it?

Maybe I'll show you the pictures for understand:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: You can't run php from .html files

Comment: you need to change extension of your file from `.html` to `.php`

Answer (score 0):

As seen in your image, you use `.html` as extention, but you have to rename file to end on `.php` and upload to a webserver that can execute PHP, like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html).

Comment: He's probably doing this on a server that can parse PHP, given all the .php files there. :) You can also parse `.html` pages for PHP code though.

Comment: I've make session_start() in my menu.html, but when I use a variable to house a value from $_SESSION['id_user']

Comment: wait... `menu.html`.. you know that only `.php` can.. well.. execute PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start session before use of it.

For example:

```
session_start();
$id_user = $_SESSION["id_user"];
```

Comment: he started the session, look at the second image. won't give you a dislike doe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've set up your server to parse `.html` pages for PHP code. If this isn't the case: do that first with a `.htaccess` file with the following: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html`. Otherwise simply rename your file from `menu.html` to `menu.php`.

I'm not seeing the top of your `menu.html` page, but I'm guessing you haven't done a `session_start()` there. Any page that wants to use `$_SESSION` variables must have the session opened *before any output to the browser*. Meaning: you need to have `<?php session_start(); ?>` before your HTML.